# Unable to bind click event : H is undefined error

Tags: jquery

I have removed click event by using `$('#div_id').unbind('click');` but after some condition I want to add click event for the same div. I used as `$('#div_id').bind('click');`.

But it gives error in firbug as `H is undefined` and so that I am not able to retain it's on click event.

I am using `jquery.min.js` . Is it because of minified version of jquery?

Thank You.

Comment: You forgot the event handler -- look at the syntax carefully: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: hey thanx, firstly I just updated my jquery.min.js to latest version, so its not giving any error and then added event handler.. now it works.. +1 for your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- define the handler function externally
- and use that like below

  ```
   function handlerFunction() {
     // code for click hander
    }

    $('#div_id').bind('click', handlerFunction);
  ```

Because you must have to set the handlerFunction with event ***[bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)***.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include the function handler for the click event. Also, if you're concerned  about swapping click events for specific div elements (but not all events) then just consider using the JQuery delegate event handler to the parent element and then just using some state variable to identify if an element has "no" event click operation behind it.